# NPM script for Heroku deployment Vue&Express app

Tags: git, heroku, vue.js, deployment, npm-scripts

I would like to create npm script allowing me to build and deploy Vue & Node app to public host, in my case it is Heroku.

My app structure looks like this:

- client                         // Vue front-end

  - dist                         // built files
  - node_modules
  - public
  - src                         // source code
  - babel.config.js
  - package.json
  - package-lock.json
- server                     // Node back-end

  - node_modules
  - src

    - config // configuration files
    - controllers
    - models
    - routes
    - app.js // starting file
  - package.json
  - package-lock.json
- package.json
- .gitignore

On my git `master` branch that is pushed on GitLab repo I am ignoring `/dist` from `client` directory and `index.js` file from `server/src/config` where I store secret keys. 
Is there any possibility to write one npm script that would build Vue app, and push only `/dist` and `/server` directories (including ignored `index.js` file as it is needed for production)?
Thanks in advance.